# Unable to call request permission code in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-6.0-marshmallow

I changed my application android version to 6.0 in eclipse and I copied all Jars related to it into libs as appcompat and all. And changed my BaseActivity to AppCompatActivity but checkSelfPermission method not found and showing error in eclipse as screenshot attached. I don't know why it happen? please suggest me any solution regarding the same. I want to run my code on 6.0.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I already seen that, and please check the problem of mine and him, I am asking for eclipse not for android studio. I changed my android version to 23.

Comment: Yes, the same I told you that I am using 23 and copied all supported files to libs as Appcompat and all.

Comment: I noticed you've created a new tag, perhaps "android-m" or "android-marshmallow" would be more appropriate. Further more, you've incorrectly spelt "marshmallow". :)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I edited the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the method `checkSelfPermission()` to compile in Eclipse you can simply add `android-support-compat.jar` as taken from [here](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-compat/tree/28.0.0) to the `libs` folder of your Eclipse project.